# Array testing with Should

Tags: node.js, should.js

I'm trying to make the test for an this array using the node extension should:

```
{validationError: 
   [{field: 'name', rule: 'string'},
    {field: 'name', rule: 'minLength' },
    {field: 'name', rule: 'required'}] 
}
```

I have no clue on how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to test?

Comment: That all the field of the array and sub array are present.

Answer (score 0):

Create a *tests* folder in your project,

put the below in a file called *FieldsTest.js*,

and run *npm test* from your project's root.

```
'use strict';
var should = require('should');

describe('SO tests', function() {
  it('should pass', function() {
    var x={validationError:
       [{field: 'name', rule: 'string'},
        {field: 'name', rule: 'minLength' },
        {field: 'name', rule: 'required'}]
    };
    x.validationError.forEach(function(y) {
      y.hasOwnProperty("field").should.eql(true);
      y.hasOwnProperty("rule").should.eql(true);
    });
  });

  it('should fail', function() {
    var x={validationError:
       [{field: 'name', rule: 'string'},
        {field: 'name', rule: 'minLength' },
        {field: 'name'}]
    };
    x.validationError.forEach(function(y) {
      y.hasOwnProperty("field").should.eql(true);
      y.hasOwnProperty("rule").should.eql(true);
    });
  });

});
```